# Can VB6 be used to realize SOAP web service?

Tags: soap, vb6

I have a exe application written in VB6, now I want to make it support SOAP web service, so other clients can access the data it provided. I know vb.net can support SOAP web service well, I do not want to upgrade it to vb.net, how can I realize SOAP web service in VB6?

Comment: You can probably implement a component that implements web service support using C# or VB.Net and make it COM-visible. Then you can easily use it from VB6.

Comment: SOAP is all but dead, largely replaced by RESTful alternatives.  However either way it means rewriting the program as a server, usually as part of an IIS application of some kind instead of as a standalone service itself.  You might also get by using Apache on Windows or something but then you are in the murkey realm of CGI.

Comment: @xxbbcc Good idea! but can you give me more guide to write a component and call it from VB6?

Comment: @xxbbcc The application should be a web service server, so it mean the component should call VB6 to obtain data and return the data in SOAP to client, instead of calling web service from VB6.